# New to python invalid syntax*update

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to finish a program for one of my classes but I keep getting invalid syntax, python is extremely new to me so bear with my ignorance.

The invalid syntax is popping up at the colon in "if guess==(num_x+num_y):"
If anyone could help I would much appreciate it.

---

update*
fixed the parentheses thank you abarnert but now I have the following `SyntaxError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Franz\Desktop\randomstudy.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Franz\Desktop\randomstudy.py", line 25, in main
    guess=int(input(num_x, "-", num_y, "=\n"))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

I have updated the below code to included the parentheses.

```
def main():
    import random
    num_x=random.randint(-50,50)
    num_y=random.randint(-50,50)
    op=random.randint(0,3)
    control=True 
    print("Welcome! Here is your random problem:\n")   
    if op==0:
        while True:
            guess=int(input(num_x, "+", num_y, "=\n"))
            if guess==(num_x+num_y):
                print("Congratulations! You have answered the problem correctly!")
                break     
            else:
                print("I’m sorry, that is not correct.  Please try again.")
    elif op==1:
        while True:
            guess=int(input(num_x, "-", num_y, "=\n"))
            if guess==(num_x-num_y):
                print("Congratulations! You have answered the problem correctly!")
                break     
            else:
                print("I’m sorry, that is not correct.  Please try again.")
    elif op==2:
        while True:
            guess=int(input(num_x, "*", num_y, "=\n"))
            if guess==(num_x*num_y):
                print("Congratulations! You have answered the problem correctly!")
                break    
            else:
                print("I’m sorry, that is not correct.  Please try again.")
    elif op==3:
        while True:
            guess=int(input(num_x, "/", num_y, "=(Please round to two decimal places)\n"))
            if guess==(num_x/num_y):
                print("Congratulations! You have answered the problem correctly!")
                break    
            else:
                print("I’m sorry, that is not correct.  Please try again.")

main()
```

Comment: Add missing `)` to the end of `int(input(num_x, "+", num_y, "=\n")` (plus the same for two other instances of `int(input(..`)

Comment: In the future, don't just say "invalid syntax", paste the actual `SyntaxError` and traceback. This one was easy, but often it will take more work to find the problem, and it's much easier if we can see all the details Python gave you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line right before that is missing a ')':

```
    guess=int(input(num_x, "+", num_y, "=\n")
    if guess==(num_x+num_y):
```

As Igor points out in the comments, you have other lines that are also missing closing parentheses, and you have to fix them as well, or you'll just get another `SyntaxError` a few lines down. You may want to consider using an editor that helps out with balancing parentheses and similar problems—it certainly makes my life a lot easier.

This isn't quite as common in Python as with most other languages, but it does happen often enough that you should be used to looking at the previous line whenever you get an inexplicable `SyntaxError`.

(In most languages, almost any expression or statement can continue onto the next line. That's not true in Python—but if there's an open parenthesis, the parenthesized expression *is* allowed to continue onto the next line.)

Comment: in all statements your are missing closing parentheses